# Checking if file path is readable and writable

Tags: c

I am trying to list all the files and sub directories recursively given a file path. This works, until when I try to add the code to check if the file path is readable/writeable(which I commented the lines out). It now does not go into the recursive loop. This is my code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void listDir(char *name, FILE *fp)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        FILE *fileCopy;
        char read[50];
        char write[50];
        char path[1024];
        int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
        path[len] = 0;
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
           // if((fileCopy = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL){
           //     strcpy(read,"Not Readable");
           // }
           // else{
           //     strcpy(read,"Readable");
           // }
           // if((fileCopy = fopen(path, "wb")) == NULL){
           //     strcpy(write,"Not Writable");
           // }
           // else{
           //     strcpy(write,"Writable");
           // }
            fprintf(fp,"[D]%s - %s,%s\n", path,read,write);
            listDir(path ,fp);
        }
        else
        {
           // if((fileCopy = fopen(path, "rb")) == NULL){
           //     strcpy(read,"Not Readable");
           // }
           // else{
           //     strcpy(read,"Readable");
           // }
           // if((fileCopy = fopen(path, "wb")) == NULL){
           //     strcpy(write,"Not Writable");
           // }
           // else{
           //    strcpy(write,"Writable");
           // }
            fprintf(fp,"[F]%s - %s,%s\n", path,read,write);
        }
    } while ((entry = readdir(dir)));
    closedir(dir);

}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
      fp = fopen("/var/mobile/Applications/FileIOAccess.txt", "w");
    listDir("/var",fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(entry == readdir(dir)` ????

Comment: I believe its not that error but anw tried it, now there is no output in the file

Comment: You were assigning the value to entry which is erroneous for `while` looping structure...[This](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) can be helpful...try to change the condition as per the information in Return Value section...

Comment: this code works if I do not include the commented codes. However once i add them in, it does not go into the recursive. I do not understand why an if-else statement would cause such changes as i am only doing checking in the if-else statement

Comment: Your if-else statements are absolutely not only performing checking. Opening a file for writing with `fopen(path, "wb")` will truncate it -- set the file length to zero. Running this code on every file in a directory will essentially wipe out every file. If you want to use `fopen` to test the permissions of a file this way, you will have to use `fopen(path, "a")` to avoid destroying it. As to why the code does not descend recursively when this code is included, it is unclear, but I strongly recommend that you learn how to check `errno` and print standard error messages to learn why calls fail.

Comment: OP, honestly you should get rid of the commented code and use `access` or `stat`.  `access` is easier but only tests the file permissions against the real user id.  If you need to test against the effective user id then use `stat`.

Comment: Since you're never calling `fclose` for any `fopen` that succeeds, at some point you'll hit the per-process file descriptor limit and all other `fopen`s and `opendir`s will fail,

Comment: Just 1 more question. If i use a as parameter instead of wb,the file would not be truncated?

Comment: No it won't be truncated but you have the potential for creating the file if it didn't exist.  Let's say that in between the time you read the file name from the dir and open the file another user or process deletes the file you are about to open in append mode.  You will end up recreating the file that was just deleted.  This is a very small chance but it could happen and most people don't expect a directory listing program to start creating files on their own.

Comment: So using access or stat would be better? Do you have any links which shows example of using them, or if possible u can post your answer here using access or stat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example uses `access` to replace your use of `fopen` to test the file permissions.

```
void listDir(char *name, FILE *fp)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do
    {
        char readString[50]  = {0};
        char writeString[50] = {0};
        char path[1024];
        char filetype;

        snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);

        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        if (access(path, R_OK) == 0)
            strcpy(readString, "Readable");
        else
            strcpy(readString, "Not Readable");

        if (access(path, W_OK) == 0)
            strcpy(writeString, "Writable");
        else
            strcpy(writeString, "Not Writable");

        switch (entry->d_type)
        {
            case  DT_UNKNOWN: filetype = '?'; break;
            case  DT_FIFO:    filetype = 'P'; break;
            case  DT_CHR:     filetype = 'C'; break;
            case  DT_DIR:     filetype = 'D'; break;
            case  DT_BLK:     filetype = 'B'; break;
            case  DT_REG:     filetype = 'F'; break;
            case  DT_LNK:     filetype = 'L'; break;
            case  DT_SOCK:    filetype = 'S'; break;
            case  DT_WHT:     filetype = 'W'; break;
            default:          filetype = '?'; break;
        }

        fprintf(fp,"[%c]%s - %s,%s\n", filetype, path, readString, writeString);

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
           listDir(path, fp);

    } while ((entry = readdir(dir)));

    closedir(dir);
}
```

Comment: Just 1 more question, not sure if you are familiar with this. Lets say I am writing a console application for a jailbroken iphone. Is there any difference using stat(), access() or fopen()? Apparently I tried using fopen() and access() and most of the iphone system paths give me readable and writeable which I am not convinced.

Comment: As I mentioned above the main difference is that `access` uses the real user/group ids to test against the file permissions.  With `stat` you have the choice of testing permissions against the effective user/group as well.  I don't know anything much about the iphone or jail breaking it.  Perhaps the jail breaking process changes the permissions or elevates your user privileges?