# traversing directories using depth first search in linux c

Tags: c, linux, depth-first-search

Here is the recursive code, which traverses through all the directories using depth first search logic.

```
void listdir(const char *name, int level)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            path[len] = 0;
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            printf("%*s%s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, level + 1);
        }
        else{
            printf("%*s- %s\n", level*2, "", entry->d_name);
        }
    } while (entry = readdir(dir));
    closedir(dir);
}
```

The code is working but I am not getting the required output, here is my output:

```
dir C
- my3.dat
dir A
- my2.dat
dir B
-my1.dat
- my1.dat
```

But the required output is:

```
dir C
- my3.dat
-dir A
dir B
- my1.dat
-my1.dat
- my2.dat
```

The structure of my folders is:

- `dir A`, `dir C` in main folder
- `dir C` has `my3.dat` only
- `dir A` contains `dir B` and `my1.dat` and `my2.dat`
- `dir B` contains `my1.dat`

Comment: Code copied straight from http://stackoverflow.com/q/20648793/2564301. So do you understand what it is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output looks completely correct to me given that `opendir` and `readdir` iterate through directory entries in the order in which they appear which is mostly determined by the order in which the files were created.

If you want to sort in a different order, you'll need to read the entries of a directory, perform a sort and then iterate through them in the sorted order.